# How to create array of generic associated type protocol in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Better to ask with example. So its table sections and rows

First created a protocol which needs to be implemented by all rows which has an associated type, must be given by caller to tell while defining row.

```
protocol RowElementProtocol {
    associatedtype ElementType
    var cellIdentifier: String {get set}
    var cellType: ElementType {get set}
}
```

So creating a generic row struct here

```
struct GenericRow <T>: RowElementProtocol {

    var cellIdentifier = "cell"
    var cellType: T

    /// Some Other Properties

    init(cellIdentifier: String = "cell", cellType: T) {

        self.cellIdentifier = cellIdentifier
        self.cellType = cellType
    }
}
```

Creating a different row struct here

```
struct DifferentRow<T>: RowElementProtocol {

    var cellIdentifier = "cell"
    var cellType: T

    /// Some Different Properties other then generic
}
```

Now creating a section which can have any kind of rows

```
struct Section<T: RowElementProtocol> {

    var rows = 1
    var rowElements: [T]
}
```

Everything is fine here, Problem arises when I want to initialise an array of sections

```
let sections = [Section<T: RowElementProtocol>]()
```

Compiler is not allowing me to initialise. Its showing ">' is not a postfix unary operator".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have a look at the consequences of the compiler allowing you to create such an array.

You could do something like this:

```
var sections = [Section<T: RowElementProtocol>]()
var sec1 = Section<GenericRow<String>>()
var sec2 = Section<DifferentRow<Int>>()
sections.append(sec1)
sections.append(sec2)
let foo = sections[0] // how can the compiler know what type this is?
```

See the problem now? "Well, `foo` can just be of type `Section<T: RowElementProtocol>`" you might say. Okay, let's suppose that's true:

```
foo.rowElements[0].cellType // what the heck is the type of this?
```

The compiler has no idea. It only knows that `foo.rowElements[0]` is "some type that conforms to `RowElementProtocol` but `cellType` could be anything.

"Okay, why not just use `Any` for that type?" you might ask. The compiler *could* do this, but that makes your generics pointless, doesn't it?

If you *want* to make your generics pointless, you can do what's called "type erasure", by creating the types `AnyRowElement` and `AnySection`:

```
struct AnyRowElement : RowElementProtocol {
    var cellIdentifier: String

    var cellType: Any

    typealias ElementType = Any

    init<T: RowElementProtocol>(_ x: T) {
        self.cellIdentifier = x.cellIdentifier
        self.cellType = x.cellType
    }
}

struct AnySection {
    var rows: Int
    var rowElements: [AnyRowElement]

    init<T: RowElementProtocol>(_ x: Section<T>) {
        self.rows = x.rows
        self.rowElements = x.rowElements.map(AnyRowElement.init)
    }
}

let sections: [AnySection] = [AnySection(sec1), AnySection(sec2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the compiler what the implemented type of T is

```
let sections = [Section<GenericRow<String>>]()
```

or like this

```
typealias SectionType = Section<GenericRow<String>>
let sections = [SectionType]()
```

Comment: But now it's not generic any more. Now yours row associated type should always be String.

Comment: @AnoopRawat At some point you need to define the content. A better example than `String` would have been some (non-generic) protocol that all row elements need to implement.

Comment: Agree. But I want that point should be when someone appending value to the array.  Or is it like, Section array must know what kind of elements are inside it.

Comment: @AnoopRawat yes it does and you do to so you know what properties you can access and what functions to call on the elements of the array